# Incrementing one of the classnames of an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of div elements with three class names each. There is an image inside each one. They're consecutively numbered (`i1, i2, i3`...) through class names. The class names are something like `"img small i14"`. I need to increment the numbers of these class names for each element.

So: for each of these div elements I need to change the class starting with **i** - add 1 or subtract 1 from it. Hopefully there is an efficient way of doing this.

The goal of the whole thing is to create a rotating image gallery. I'd much appreciate help, either through helping with the code or offering a better way of approaching the problem. Thank you.

Comment: _I need to increment the numbers of these class names for each element._ on DOMReady/ click / hover /...?

Comment: The whole thing would trigger on clicking another element.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to number elements using class names. Please tell us what you are trying to do with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine Pointy's regExp with undefined's jQuery attribute setter you get this:

```
$(a selector).attr('class', function (index, attrValue) {
    return attrValue.replace(/\bi(\d+)\b/, function (match, $1) { 
        return 'i' + (Number($1) + 1);
    });
});
```

Which works fine (cross browsers i suppose), since the class is an html attribute.

EDIT: To check whether it's the last image or not you'll have to know how many images it is in that container, so you'll have to have a jquery selector that just matches the images in one of the containers.
The code would look like this:

```
var number_of_elements = $(the selector).length;

$(the selector).attr('class', function (index, attrValue) {
    return attrValue.replace(/\bi(\d+)\b/, function (match, $1) { 
        var number = Number($1);
        if (number === number_of_elements) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 'i' + (number + 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's great, but how can I make it return to 1 if it reaches a certain number? Thanks.

Comment: Then you would do an if statement in the replace function to check whether the number $1 is === the number of images in that container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Everything works wonderfully now.

Comment: @user1692406 This **will not work** in old versions of Internet Explorer, and it's simply incorrect in modern browsers. The class should be set via the "className" **property** (not attribute) of a DOM element. Thus, if you *must* use jQuery, and you're using a version newer than 1.6, use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Hey. I tried it in IE6 and IE7 and it seems to work. The minimal testcase i did was: `$('img').attr('class', 'newClass'); alert(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].className);` and (on a page with an img) it alerted newClass. Is there something I'm missing in this testcase?

Comment: Found this in the jQuery source in the attr setter function: `// Fallback to prop when attributes are not supported
  if ( typeof elem.getAttribute === "undefined" ) {
   return jQuery.prop( elem, name, value );
  }` which probably explains why it works even though the className as you say is an an javascript attribute on the element.

Comment: Link to source [link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L301)  ps it's a combined getter setter function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any jQuery tool that makes this easier. I'd just do it with plain JavaScript:

```
function updateIndex( className ) {
  return className.replace(/\bi(\d+)\b/, function(_, n) {
    return 'i' + ((+n) + 1);
  });
}
```

Then you can just pass the "className" property of your element to that, and update "className" to the return value:

```
element.className = updateIndex( element.className );
```

Comment: Maybe `attr` in this case: `$('.img').attr('class', function(ind, currentClass){// return... })`

Comment: @undefined no, setting the class name like that is incorrect. The class should always be set as a property on the element, not as an attribute. The property is called "className" because "class" is a reserved word in JavaScript. (Setting it as an attribute may work in newer browsers but it fails in old Internet Explorer; there's really no point anyway since setting the "className" property works everywhere and involves no function calls.)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I meant jQuerish way. I  prefer your approach.

Comment: @undefined since jQuery 1.6 (I think) there's a new method, `.prop()`, that's like `.attr()` but for element properties (like "id", "name", "href", "src" - anything that's kept in the DOM as a direct DOM element property).

Comment: @Pointy Yes, `prop` is a useful method specially when you are dealing with form controls.